# Segmentation Fault on reading a binary file on struct array

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault, g++

So, the binary file literally stores just one struct array

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Card{
    char symbol;
    int color;
    int id;
};

int main(){
    int numcards = 12;
    Card *cardArray[numcards];


    ifstream arch;
    arch.open("casoPruebaParte1.dat", ios::binary); 
    
    if(!arch.is_open()){
        cout<<"Error al abrir el archivo\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    numcards = 12;
    arch.read((char*)&cardArray, numcards*sizeof(Card));

    for(int i=0; i<numcards; i++ ){
        cout << cardArray[i]->id << endl;
    }

    arch.close();

    return 0;
}
```

the error is: segmentation fault (core dumped) and debugging shows this:
[error in line 30 ( cout << cardArray[i]->id << endl;)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgi0L.png)

Comment: `Card *cardArray[numcards];` declares an array of uninitialized pointers, not an array of `Card` objects. You likely want `Card cardArray[numcards];` You should also know that variable length arrays are not standard C++ so your code will not be portable. Consider `std::vector<Card>` instead.

Comment: The issue with unnecessary pointer as explained in the previous comment, but `std::vector` is not quite necessary - `numcards` is constant and known at compile time. If you make it `constexpr int numcards  = 12;` (and remove the assignment later on), it's valid C++.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I disagree. `std::vector` or `std::array` should be used. Unless the entire program is written in main and you actually want to do stuff with those cards you'll need to pass the array to functions, and pass the size everywhere as well. Using a standard container means you don't need to worry about that, and if you use a resizable container and do a little extra work to handle a variable sized file you don't have to change any other code when you add or subtract cards. But, just my two cents.